# Where can I find the natvis schema definition (for creating VC++ debugger visualizers)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

Various online sources tell me I can find it @ %VSINSTALLDIR%\Xml\Schemas\natvis.xsd.
But I have not been able to find it in the said path. I have checked multiple VS2010 and VS2012 installations.
Can anyone paste the schema definition here?
Any additional documentation would be awesome

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\natvis.xsd

Answer (score 5):

Hans Passant commented with the right answer, but it's not immediately obvious from his posting why you (or I) originally couldn't find it, which is:

*The natvis XSD isn't found in `\Schemas`, but in `\Schemas\1033`*.

You have to dig one level deeper to find it, because apparently Microsoft thinks it's code-page-localized or something.  Anyway, here's where I located it in my copies of Visual Studio:

**Visual Studio 2012:**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\natvis.xsd`

**Visual Studio 2013:**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\natvis.xsd`

---

Also, for what it's worth, the URL that Microsoft provides for the schema, `http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010`, is a 3xx redirect as of this writing, so don't bother looking there.

Comment: Here is a link to a schema: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis#_schema working as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Xml\Schemas\1033\natvis.xsd`

Comment: Of course, replace "Professional" with your respective SKU (Enterprise in my case)

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Xml\Schemas\1033\natvis.xsd